# Custom AWS login domain

Tags: amazon-web-services

My old company has custom AWS login URLs that look like this:

```
https://company-us-aws-dev.signin.aws.amazon.com/console
https://company-us-aws-qa.signin.aws.amazon.com/console
https://company-us-aws-stage.signin.aws.amazon.com/console
https://company-us-aws-prod.signin.aws.amazon.com/console
```

And when you would click on any of the above links, you would see a login page that looks like this:

[image: AWS Sign In]

It's a login page that gives you a chance to switch to your aws root account. But I don't know what this page is called.

I now need to set this up at my new company. Is there any documentation you can point me to, or instruction you can give for how to do this?

I need to find out how to create these custom URLs in DNS and how to point those url's to these sign on screens. If I just create an A record in DNS and point it to an AWS IP, I just get a 404 screen when I go that URL in my browser.

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simple, create an account alias

- Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the IAM console at
  https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/.
- On the navigation pane, select Dashboard.
- Find the IAM users sign-in link, and click Customize to the right of
  the link.
- Type the name you want to use for your alias, then click Yes, Create.
- To remove the alias, click Customize, and then click Yes, Delete. The
  sign-in URL reverts to using your AWS account ID.

[more info](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/console_account-alias.html)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything in DNS for this - it's all within Amazon's Zone.

The bits you need to configure this are on the [front page of the IAM dashboard](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/console.html#user-sign-in-page).

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cent..If you have multiple AWS accounts than rather creating different set of bookmark for each url, think of using a single HTML page for ease of use.

Cheers!